# Setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin CORS for wordpress site

Tags: ajax, wordpress, cors, same-origin-policy

I had some problems to set a correct cors header for using external resource in my wordpress installation. I have a subdomain which exposed by another domian name.

I've got following error by using some plugin which load resources from my website by using an ajax call:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load [resource-URL] No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a .htaccess file in the root directory of my subdomain.The file content is:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "sub.site.com"
```

I read in many blogs that you should use

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

but i guess that is a bad idea.